# Configuration of enp0s3, enp0s8 interfaces on Centos

Tags: networking, ip, configuration, interface

I'm looking forward for assistance to configure interface enp0s3 which shall be used for client connection.

As well as enp0s8 interface which one is dedicated for administration purposes.

Currently those interfaces are configured:

```
# cat ifcfg-enp0s3

TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=86cadfd2-3002-4bae-b215-74de3ad9497f
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=172.160.0
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=172.16.0.1

# cat ifcfg-enp0s8

HWADDR=08:00:27:3B:5E:E3
TYPE=Ethernet
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yeS
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s8
UUID=b7437b57-1f9b-3188-a769-0d0e0fb7e73c
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
AUTOCONNECT_PRIORITY=-999
```

## route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref  Use Iface
0.0.0.0        172.16.0.1         0.0.0.0        UG    100    0   0 enp0s3
10.0.4.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0    U     100    0   0 enp0s9
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0    U     100    0   0 enp0s3

IP's for both interfaces are assign from the subnet 192.168.0.0/29 GW 192.168.0.1
An extra peripherals ( printers, backup, monitoring etcetera) are in network 212.0.45.0/24 and are reached over second interface (enp0s3) GW.

Comment: and whats exactly is the question or should be solved? in the current situation its not possible to help you, routing table is missing at first and what you originally want to solve

Comment: The task is to pick  IP's  from subnet 192.168.0.0/29 and assign them to interfaces enp0s3 and enp0s8. Current Configuration of interfaces are wrong. I'm newbie  so please don't be  critical :).

Comment: try to set a correct ipaddress, in your exemple ```IPADDR=172.160.0``` is not a correct ipaddress. And then, ask for what stop you. from what you describe we dont understant what you want.